# Python How to fill a customized value (such as "#NA####') with bfill method?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a data frame containing "#NA####". I want to back-fill this value with group mean.

I know I can first replace "#NA####" with np.NAN, then use pd.fillna, but are there any more convenient ways?

Comment: No, no convenient ways, that's how you'd have to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df

  Group   Value
0      1      10
1      1  #NA###
2      3       5
3      2      10
4      2  #NA###
5      3  #NA###
6      1      40
7      2  #NA###
8      3     100
9      1      20
```

Call `pd.to_numeric`, to coerce those strings to NaNs.

```
df.Value = pd.to_numeric(df.Value, errors='coerce')
```

Now, group by `Group`, and call `fillna` with the `mean` -

```
df = df.set_index('Group').Value\
       .fillna(df.groupby('Group').mean().Value)\
       .reset_index()
df

   Group       Value
0      1   10.000000
1      1   23.333333
2      3    5.000000
3      2   10.000000
4      2   10.000000
5      3   52.500000
6      1   40.000000
7      2   10.000000
8      3  100.000000
9      1   20.000000
```

---

An alternative fill method (from a now deleted answer) which I thought was pretty good involves `groupby` + `transform` -

```
df.Value = df.Value.fillna(df.groupby('Group')['Value'].transform('mean'))
df

       Group       Value
    0      1   10.000000
    1      1   23.333333
    2      3    5.000000
    3      2   10.000000
    4      2   10.000000
    5      3   52.500000
    6      1   40.000000
    7      2   10.000000
    8      3  100.000000
    9      1   20.000000
```